# Make Apache return simple message for specific url

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there any way to tell apache to return the word "success" for a specific url without the corresponding file even existing?

Answer (score 3):

Tested with Apache 2.4:

```
<Location /cajuzinho>
    ErrorDocument 200 "mermao"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [R=200]
</Location>
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule for more info

Answer (score 2):

Without *any* file existing on the server? No. Apache is a great web server, but that's really all it does - serve files (or dynamic content through modules, but the concept is essentially similar). A quick read of the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) seems to indicate that something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/someurl - [R=204]
```

*should* respond to a web request with a "success, no content" HTTP status code. Not exactly what you're after, but might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the specific url to i.e. succes.php:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/your-specific-url
>   RewriteRule .* /succes.php

And put in succes.php:

> <?php
>   header("text/html");
>   echo "success";
>   ?>

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I just want it to intercept a url and return "success" without relying on an actual file existing

Comment: "/your-specific-url" does not need to exist. If you mean you don't want a "success.php" then I don't know.. :)